# User sign in to a MVC application from another website or through web service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here's the situation: the user is able to sign into a MVC application from another website. That website is not ASP.NET-based. It could be PHP, JSP or Websphere... or anything

I have tried doing this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public string RemoteLogOn(string userName, string password)
 {

     if (userName != null && password != null)
     {                  
          if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(userName, password))
          {
               FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
               return "success";

          }
          else
          {
                return "failed";
          }                
      }
      else
      {
           return "failed";
      }    
}
```

Calling the MVC app at the /RemoteLogOn URI (posting the request using PHP and cURL) works. The "success" string is returned. However, it seems that the cookie is not generated properly - when I returned to the MVC site and check `User. Identity.Name`, null is returned.

What is the right way to allow user to log in via. a web service?

**Edit** How do I properly set the returned cookie.

PS. This is just a trial POC; eventually we'll use SOAP or REST and try to improve the security.

Here's the PHP code that did the calling

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost:54134/Account/RemoteLogOn";
$fields = array(
            "userName" => "asd1234",
            "password" => "****"
        );

 foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>';

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
</php>
```

Debugging the app shows the user name and password are passed in properly to the MVC side.

Comment: This is a good question but with very poor info. How are you making the call now? Instead of checking `User.Identity.Name` you need to check the cookie and see if it is there. Do you then use the cookie again?

Comment: The call is made from PHP using cURL. Added the details in if it is relevant. I am mostly checking if the cookie exists through User.Identity. Do I need to manually check for the presence of the cookie and then process it?

Comment: Then do you put back the cookie you receive to the response on the PHP? If not, then the cookie is lost.

Comment: No, I don't know how do that; figuring this out on my own. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK what you need to do is save the cookie that comes back from your cURL request and make sure it gets sent with subsequent requests.

This is how to set where to store cookies (and include in subsequent requests) in PHP:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'mycookiefile');
```

You'll need the cookie filename to be constant through the process, so I would suggest using a variable and initialising it thus:

```
$cookieFile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
```

You can get more details on this at the PHP documentation site:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/some/path/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/some/path/cookies.txt');
```

This should do the trick. As you need to store the cookies and send them back. Otherwise each request would be treated as if its coming from a completely different user.

Answer (score 1):

This becomes a curl and PHP question then. I do not know curl and know little PHP but should be easy:

- Take the authorisation cookie by checking the value of `Set-Cookie` header
- parse the value which is in the format of `.ASPXAUTH=<Cookie Value>` and get the cookie value
- Set the cookie in PHP
- In all subsequent calls, get the value of the cookie from client and send to server using curl

Comment: If the user goes over to the MVC website, will the cookie be preserved?

Comment: No. Cookie is set for the PHP site so browser would keep sending it. PHP site cannot set the cookie for MVC site since it is against privacy policies.

Comment: Think about where the cookie is stored - the PHP to MVC is a independent session.  If the user visits the MVC site in their browser, that will be another session. Remember the cookie in the PHP communication is stored in some temp directory, nothing to do with the user's browser.

Comment: Is there any way then to sign in on the PHP end, and have the user remain signed on at the MVC side?

Comment: As I said, it is illegal to set a cookie for another website. I do not know of a way you could get this working with one sign-in works for both sites.